# Why Geometry intersection does not give the expected result with polylines with more than one line?

Tags: wpf, geometry, intersection, polyline

I need to calculate the intersection between two geometries to check if one is fully inside the other or not.

The Geometry "container", based on a `System.Windows.Shapes.Polygon`, is created as follows:

```
List<PathSegment> basePolygonSegments = new List<PathSegment> {  
           new PolyLineSegment(basePolygon.Points, true) };
PathGeometry baseGeometry = new PathGeometry();
   baseGeometry.Figures.Add(
       new PathFigure(basePolygon.Points[0], basePolygonSegments, true));
```

The Geometry "contained" can be:

- another `System.Windows.Shapes.Polygon`
- a `System.Windows.Shapes.Polyline`, that can have only one line or three lines (the shape is a |_|, or U)

The Polyline is created as follows:

```
Polyline bracketDrawingPolyline = new Polyline();
foreach(Point p in listOfPoints)
bracketDrawingPolyline.Points.Add(p);

LineGeometry lineGeometry = 
     new LineGeometry(
      bracketDrawingPolyline.Points[0],
      bracketDrawingPolyline.Points[bracketDrawingPolyline.Points.Count - 1]);
PathGeometry bracketGeometry = new PathGeometry();
bracketGeometry = lineGeometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry(
         new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.0));
```

To understand if the "contained" Geometry is contained in the "container", I do the following:

```
CombinedGeometry intersectionGeometry = 
  new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, 
     baseGeometry, bracketGeometry);

double intersectionArea = 
     intersectionGeometry.GetArea(0.0001, ToleranceType.Absolute);
double bracketArea = bracketGeometry.GetArea(0.0001, ToleranceType.Absolute);


if (intersectionArea < bracketArea)
{
   //the second Geometry is not fully contained in the "container" Geometry
}

else
//it is fully contained
....
```

In case of Polygon or Polyline with only one line everything works as expected. But with Polyline U, `intersectionArea` and `bracketArea` are always the same.

I've also tried to perform the following checks:

```
bool result = baseGeometry.FillContains(bracketGeometry);
IntersectionDetail idtl =  
         baseGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(bracketGeometry);
```

but I have the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution on my own, but I don't know if it is the best one.
Considered that with a single line everything works well, I just do the check for each line of the polyline, that is:

```
for (int i = 1; i < bracketDrawingPolyline.Points.Count; i++)
{
     LineGeometry lineGeometry = 
       new LineGeometry(bracketDrawingPolyline.Points[i - 1],
       bracketDrawingPolyline.Points[i]);
     ...//continue with the check of the line as described in the post...
}
```